# Is it a good idea to add custom watcher to webpack config?

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

I have a project running with vue-CLI. I need to add some custom logic to my compilation process (in short, I want to generate some file when something was changed in /assets/ directory).

After some thinking I decided to add custom webpack plugin and watch changes manually in this plugin. But I have some doubts about performance and also isn't it an overhead or bad practice.

This is the plugin:

```
class customWebpackWatcher {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('customWatcher', compilation => {
      const changedTimes = compilation.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes;
      if (changedTimes) {
        // some logic here...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I use it in my vue.config.js (the same as webpack.config.js in vue-cli) as a usual plugin. So it's executed every compilation.